# What is the third (matroid) flat axiom?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, axioms, matroids

Given: a finite set $E$ and a set family $\mathscr{F} \subseteq 2^E = \mathscr{P}(E)$.

Every source known to me gives these as the first two  axioms for $\mathscr{F}$ to be a family of matroid flats:

1. $E \in \mathscr{F}$.
2. $F_1, F_2 \in \mathscr{F} \implies F_1 \cap F_2 \in \mathscr{F}$.

> **Question:** (a) What is the correct form for the third axiom? Can it be stated precisely?
>
> (b) What is the conclusion of the third axiom when applied to $E \in \mathscr{F}$?

E.g. how should one understand "the empty set partitions the empty set"? Isn't the empty union equal to $\emptyset$, not to $E$? And if the third axiom makes no sense when applied to $E$, and $E \in \mathscr{F}$ is only included so that $\mathscr{F}$ isn't empty, then why not say $E \not\in \mathscr{F}, \mathscr{F} \not= \emptyset \subseteq 2^E$?

---

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Flats) says: 3. If $F \in \mathscr{F}$, then the set of all $G \in \mathscr{F}$ which cover $F$ (meaning that $G \supsetneq F$ but there is no $H \in \mathscr{F}$ between $F$ and $G$) partition the elements of $E \setminus F$.

[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521092027) gives two supposedly equivalent forms:
3.(a) If $G_1, \dots, G_k \in \mathscr{F}$ is the family of flats which cover $F \in \mathscr{F}$ (i.e. each $G_i$ contains $F$ properly with no $H \in \mathscr{F}$ in between), then $G_1 \setminus F, \dots, G_k \setminus F$ partition $E \setminus F$.
3.(b) For all $F \in \mathscr{F}$, $\bigcup \{ F' \in \mathscr{F}: F' \succ F  \} = E$.

[Oxley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199603391) says: If $F \in \mathscr{F}$ and $\{ G_1, G_2, \dots, G_k\}$ is the set of minimal members of $\mathscr{F}$ that properly contain $F$, then the sets $G_1 \setminus F, G_2 \setminus F, \dots, G_k \setminus F$ partition $E \setminus F$. [These notes](http://people.math.sc.edu/cooper/math776/matroid.pdf) parrot this.

[Gordon, McNulty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521145686) say the same thing as the first axiom given by the Encyclopedia of Mathematics, except that they don't even bother to try to explain what "cover" means.

---

**Attempt:** Are either of these definitions of the "flat cover" correct?
(a) $cover: \mathscr{F} \to 2^{2^E}$, $cover: F \mapsto \{G \in \mathscr{F}: G \supsetneq F, \forall H \in \mathscr{F}, F \subseteq H \subseteq G \implies H = F \lor H = G  \}$
(b) $cover: \mathscr{F} \to 2^{2^E}$, $cover: F \mapsto \{G \in \mathscr{F}: G \supsetneq F, \forall X \in 2^E, F \subsetneq X \subsetneq G \implies X \not\in \mathscr{F} \}$

***EDIT:** What I had here before was totally wrong (among other things, it should be $G \setminus F$, not $E \setminus G$). Also the definitions of cover incorrectly said $G \supseteq F$ instead of $G \supsetneq F$.*

Then define $[cover(F) \setminus F] \in 2^{2^E}$ by $[cover(F) \setminus F] := \{ G \setminus F: G \in cover(F) \}$.

My understanding of "partition" is the following:

$[cover(F) \setminus F]$ partitions $E \setminus F$ $\iff$ $\bigsqcup\limits_{G \in cover(F)} G \setminus F = E \setminus F$, where $\bigsqcup$ denotes *disjoint* union.

***EDIT:*** *What follows is also totally incorrect and based on a false premise. We're interested in $G \setminus E$ (which does not exist because $cover(E) = \emptyset$), not in $E \setminus E$, which does exist but is the empty set. I.e. using the right definition $cover(F) \setminus F$ it is an empty union, using the wrong definition $E \setminus cover(F)$ it is a non-empty union of empty sets.*

When $F = E$, we should have that $E \setminus F = \emptyset$, so $$ \bigsqcup\limits_{X \in cover(F)} E \setminus X = \emptyset \,,$$ thus this is supposed to be either an empty union, or a non-empty union of empty set(s).

If it is supposed to be an empty union, then we should have that $cover(E) = \emptyset$. If it is supposed to be a non-empty union of empty set(s), we should have that $cover(E) = \{ E \}$.

In particular, should we have that $cover(E) = \{ E \}$ or $cover(E) = \emptyset$?

Using definition (a), $cover(E) = \{E\}$, (b) is supposed to be equivalent to (a), so to get $cover(E) = \emptyset$ one needs to change $H = F \lor H = G$ in the definition of (a) to $H = G$ or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your definitions of "cover" is correct, because you seem to have forgotten about the requirement that $G$ *strictly* contains $F$.  If $F,G\in\mathscr{F}$, then $G$ covers $F$ if $F\subsetneq G$ and there does not exist any $H\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $F\subsetneq H\subsetneq G$.

The third axiom can then be stated as follows.  For any $F\in\mathscr{F}$ and any $x\in E\setminus F$, there exists a unique $G\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $G$ covers $F$ and $x\in G$.  In other words, every element of $E\setminus F$ is in $G\setminus F$ for a unique $G$ which covers $F$, so the collection of such sets $G\setminus F$ is a partition of $E\setminus F$.

In the case $F=E$, there is nothing special going on.  There do not exist any $x\in E\setminus F$, so the requirement is vacuous.  There are also does not exist any $G\in\mathscr{F}$ which covers $F$ (since there is no element of $\mathscr{F}$ which properly contains $F$), but that is fine, since the empty set is a partition (the only partition!) of the empty set.

---

Note that actually the uniqueness requirement here can be omitted.  If $G$ and $H$ both cover $F$ and $x\in G,H$, then $G\cap H\in\mathscr{F}$ by the second axiom.  We have $F\subsetneq G\cap H \subset G$ (the first inclusion is strict since $x\in G\cap H$), so $G\cap H=G$ since $G$ covers $F$.  Similarly, $G\cap H=H$, so $G=H$.

So it suffices to assume the union of all the elements of $\mathscr{F}$ which cover $F$ contains all of $E\setminus F$.  This is almost the same as requiring that the union of all the elements of $\mathscr{F}$ which cover $F$ is $E$ itself, which is what the second definition in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics says.  Indeed, as long as there exists some element which covers $F$, then the union always contains $F$, so all that matters is whether it contains $E\setminus F$.  However, when $F=E$, there is nothing that covers $F$.  So the second definition in the Encyclopedia of Mathematics is incorrect and should be modified to only apply when $F\neq E$.

Comment: This is very helpful, especially the sanity check that something was fishy about the 2nd Encyclopedia of Mathematics definition. I really appreciate you taking all of the time to explain this. 2 questions to confirm my understanding: (1) Would either of the above two proposed "definitions" of cover be correct if $G \supseteq F$ was replaced with $G \supsetneq F$? Or are they more deeply flawed than that? (2) If $F \in \mathscr{F}$ is a hyperplane, then its cover is $E$, right? Since it is a maximal proper flat? So a flat has an empty cover if and only if it is $E$?

Comment: (1) Yes, both your definitions are correct with that correction. (2) Yes, that's correct.