# Construct a rank-3 matroid using rank-2 flat

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, projective-geometry, matroids

Let $E$ be a finite set with size bigger or equal to 3. Let $L$ be a collection of subsets of $E$ such that:

1. $2 \leq |A| < |E|$ for any $A \in L$
2. $|A \cap B| \leq 1$ for any $A, B \in L$

Now show that there exists a unique simple rank-3 matroid $M$ on $E$ such that $L$ is exactly the collection of all rank-2 flat. Also, describe the set of basis of $M$ in terms of $L$.

I have difficulty in finding those independent sets and also do not know how to define a rank function such that all elements in $L$ has rank 2. I can come up with an example like $U_{3, 4}$. In $U_{3, 4}$, $L$ is just all the set with size 2 and it is unique up to isomorphism. At least now I know that there is a matroid that can be built up in this way but fail to prove the more general theorem.

Any responses will be appreciated.

Update_1: Hinted by Joshua, I consider the characterization of flats of a matroid but used the definition from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537203/what-is-the-third-matroid-flat-axiom). This time I have trouble proving the third axiom and also do not know how to make these flats have rank 2.

Comment: Try using the cryptomorphic characterization of matroids in terms of flats: $\mathcal{F} \subseteq 2^E$ is the family of flats of a matroid $M$ if and only if contains $E$, is closed under intersection, and the flats covering $S \in \mathcal{F}$ cover $E \setminus S$.

Comment: The characterization I heard is a bit different from yours but very similar. Please check the first answer of this post for the one I used [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2537203/what-is-the-third-matroid-flat-axiom). This time I have difficulty proving the third axiom (the one about the unique cover). Also, do you have any ideas about how to make those flats have rank 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $M$ is supposed to be simple, every singleton $\{e\}$ for $e \in E$ must be a flat, and these are the flats of rank $1$. This shows uniqueness.

The conditions stated on $L$ are not enough to ensure such $M$ exists. Let $E = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $L = \{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}\}$. The sets $E$ and $L$ satisfy your conditions. But, there is no simple matroid $M$ of rank 3 on $E$ with 2-flats exactly $L$. This is because the only flat covering $\{3\}$ is $\{1,3\}$, and $\{1\}$ does not partition $\{1,2,4\}$.

Comment: That is a nice observation. Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Meanwhile I am thinking the following question: Now if I change the first condition to: $3 \leq |A| < |E|$ where in the new question the size of $E$ is at least 4, can I still find a counter example? I just put my thoughts here so you do not need to worry about this new one. However, I will definitely be glad to see your thoughts too.

Comment: $E = \{1,2,3,4,5\}, L = \{\{1,2,3\}, \{1,4,5\}\}$ has the same problem. In fact this will always be a problem for all values of $2$.